# Where to tell people how you solved the problem you asked about?

Tags: support

I asked a question recently ([Should an amateur attempt truing a wheel](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/39195/should-an-amateur-attempt-truing-a-wheel)) about truing a damged wheel on my bike. With the help (and encouragement) of the answers I got the bike into riding condition. Now I would like to somehow add a note to the question as to how I solved it (the resources I used and so forth). I assume this would be very helpful for someone in the same situation.

There are three places that seem to make sense to me:

- **Comment on the question itself**. But it might get buried in the many comments there.
- **Comment on an answer**. This would make sense if there was clearly one best answer. But often the solution is a combinaion of the answers, as in this case.
- **As a new answer to the question**. This seems a bit too grand, since I'm no expert. However, my solution is clearly an answer to my question, and I would accept someone elses answer.

Answer (score 7):

I think in this scenario a new answer is appropriate. You can mark your answer as "accepted" if you wish, although you won't gain any rep for doing so.

Comment: Yes, this is the way to go. Since you found an answer that is right for you and it wasn't already here. Other readers can see by the upvotes what the rest of the community thinks of the various answers. But your answer can be valuable to others who are new to truing wheels. Most of us have forgotten those early lessons and what we didn't know we didn't know.